# ¿Cómo convertir en Windows una ventana Pygame en una windowchild de otra ventana usando Python y PYQT5?

Tags: python, pygame

**¿Cómo integrar una ventana Pygame en otra ventana PYQT5 en Python?**

He probado varias maneras, de las cuales esta es la más conocida, pero en realidad solo sirve para posicionar la ventana y no la he podido dar verdadera utilidad para convertir la ventana **Pygame** en una ventana hija: **"Windowchild"** de otra ventana **"padre"**...

```
import os
import pygame

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (200,200)
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Pruebas Pygame")
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
```

**¿Existe alguna manera más eficaz de realizar el proceso?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La manera de integrar cualquier ventana, como hija, dentro de otra en Python y PYQT5 es como sigue:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estas son las importaciones necesarias:**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys

import win32gui
import pygame

ancho_ventana = 310
alto_ventana = 210
```

En el punto inicial de nuestra aplicación, dentro del bloque `if __name__ == "__main__":` que, por cierto, se encarga de detectar si se trata de una ejecución directa o de una importación, obtenemos el valor **"hwnd"** de la ventana principal, que según la documentación es:

```
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget.QWidget
def winId(self) -> None
winId(self) -> PyQt5.sip.voidptr
# Este texto no forma parte del código, sino que lo he reproducido de la información de PYQT5.
```

Y que pasaremos como argumento, en este caso, a la clase `VentanaPygame(window.winId())`, que es la encargada de iniciar la ventana **Pygame**.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = UiMainWindow()

    window.show()
    VentanaPygame(window.winId())

    app.exec_()
```

**Inicio de la ventana Pygame:**

```
class VentanaPygame:
    def __init__(self, windowhwnd):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pruebas Pygame")
    ventana_pygame = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 200), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

Aquí obtenemos el **"hwnd"** de la ventana **Pygame** mediante la función **"FindWindow"**, de **"win32gui"**, a la que pasaremos como segundo parámetro el título de la ventana objetivo, en este caso **"Pruebas Pygame"**; que, dicho sea de paso, puede ser cualquier otra ventana abierta en **Windows** en ese momento, como el bloc de notas, por ejemplo...

```
    pygamehwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Pruebas Pygame')
```

Seguidamente lo usaremos para asignar la ventana secundaria como **windowchild** a la ventana principal mediante la función: **"SetParent"**

```
    win32gui.SetParent(pygamehwnd, int(windowhwnd))
    win32gui.MoveWindow(pygamehwnd, 10, 30, 300, 200, True)
```

**Ventana principal de la aplicación:**

`class UiMainWindow(QMainWindow):`
Esta es una ventana sin más pretensiones que servir para integrar en ella la ventana **"child"** de **Pygame**.

**Y este es el código completo y funcional, aunque mejorable, claro está...**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys

import win32gui
import pygame

ancho_ventana = 310
alto_ventana = 210


class UiMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ancho_ventana = ancho_ventana
        self.alto_ventana = alto_ventana
        self.setFixedSize(self.ancho_ventana, self.alto_ventana)
        self.move(700, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Pygame window')

        self.actionSalir = QAction(self)
        self.actionSalir.setObjectName(u"actionSalir")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")

        self.pushButton1 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName(u"pushButton1")
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QRect(10, self.alto_ventana - 70, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton1.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton2 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName(u"pushButton2")
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QRect(90, self.alto_ventana - 70, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 310, 21))
        self.menuPrueba = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuPrueba.setObjectName(u"menuPrueba")
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuPrueba.menuAction())
        self.menuPrueba.addAction(self.actionSalir)

        self.retranslateui()

        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.close)
        # self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(VentanaPygame.escribir_pygame(VentanaPygame))
        self.actionSalir.triggered.connect(self.close)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    # setupUi

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        close = QMessageBox()
        close.setWindowTitle("Pygame window")
        close.setText("¿Desea cerrar la aplicación?")
        close.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        close.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        close = close.exec()

        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def retranslateui(self):
        self.actionSalir.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Salir", None))
        self.pushButton1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Salir", None))
        self.pushButton2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Pygame", None))
        self.menuPrueba.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Archivo", None))

    # retranslateUi


class VentanaPygame:
    def __init__(self, windowhwnd):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.font.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame")

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 200), pygame.NOFRAME)  # pygame.NOFRAME

        self.fuente_del_texto = pygame.font.SysFont('Lucida Console', 20)

        self.windowhwnd = windowhwnd
        pygamehwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Pygame')
        # hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Sin título: Bloc de notas')
        win32gui.SetParent(pygamehwnd, int(self.windowhwnd))
        win32gui.MoveWindow(pygamehwnd, 10, 30, ancho_ventana - 20, alto_ventana - 100, True)

        self.escribir_pygame('Prueba de texto Pygame...')

    def escribir_pygame(self, texto):
        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        textsurface = self.fuente_del_texto.render(texto, True, (255, 0, 0))
        self.screen.blit(textsurface, (10, 50))
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = UiMainWindow()

    window.show()
    VentanaPygame(window.winId())

    app.exec_()
```